# Using generic protocols in generic classes

Tags: class, generics, swift, constraints, protocols

I defined a protocol `LLNodeType`:

```
protocol LLNodeType {
    typealias T
    var firstNode: LLNode<T>? { get }
}
```

`LLNode<T>` is just a simple generic class, which contains a stored property of type `N`.

```
class LLNode<N> {
    var content: N
    ...
}
```

To conform to the `LLNodeType` protocol I therefore extended `LLNode` as follows:

```
extension LLNode: LLNodeType {
    typealias T = N

    var firstNode: LLNode<T>? {
        return self
    }
}
```

I also defined a generic class `LLLinkedList` containing a few properties and functions using the generic type `L`:

```
class LLLinkedList<L> {
    var rootNode: LLNode<L>?
    ...
}
```

I extended this class to conform to `LLNodeType`:

```
extension LLLinkedList: LLNodeType {
    typealias T = L

    var firstNode: LLNode<T>? {
         return self.rootNode
    }
}
```

I found a way of passing `LLNodeType` to methods of `LLLinkedList` as a regular type and used it on the `append` method:

```
func append<NT: LLNodeType>(nodeSequence: NT) {
    let nodes = LLLinkedList(nodeSequence: nodeSequence) 
    ...
}
```

As seen in the first statement of the `append` method, I have also defined an initializer for `LLLinkedList`, that takes a parameter `nodeSequence` of type `LLNodeType`:

```
convenience init<NT: LLNodeType where NT.T == L>(nodeSequence: NT) {
    self.init()
    self.rootNode = nodeSequence.firstNode
}
```

The initializer only takes a `nodeSequence` which conforms to `LLNodeType`, which is constrained though to use a type `T` equal to `L`.

The `firstNode` property of a `nodeSequence` conforming to these conditions should therefore return an `LLNode<L>?`.

Therefore the statement `self.rootNode = nodeSequence.firstNode` should be completely possible, since `self.rootNode` is of type `LLNode<L>?`.

---

When I try to compile the code, I get the error:

```
<stdin>:501:33: error: extra argument 'nodeSequence' in call
let nodes = LLLinkedList(nodeSequence: nodeSequence)
```

`501:33` refers to the first statement of the `append` method.

How can there be an `extra argument 'nodeSequence'` if I defined the initializer with an argument called `nodeSequence`?

---

Here's a code sample containing only the parts relevant to the question:
[SwiftStub-Code](http://swiftstub.com/137821597/)

Comment: Can you provide a full block of code that can be cut/pasted into a playground?  Otherwise it'll be too hard for someone to reproduce your problem.  I just tried and the code I put together from your question (plus some tweaks such as giving `LLNode` an `init`) compiled OK.  Don't get too hung up on the error message, Swift error messages are a bit misleading at the moment sometimes. Basically what it is doing is giving you the reason why it can't use the `init()` method, having ruled out your convenience method for some other reason it's not mentioning.

Comment: I have added a link at the bottom of the question. As it says it only contains parts relevant to the question. If you really like I could post the whole code-block, which is mostly irrelevant though.

Comment: The link to your actual code gave me what was needed to figure out why it didn't work – what you posted in your question didn't.  Always try to put into the question enough code to easily reproduce the problem when you can – you'll rarely get a good answer from code people can't easily try without having to write more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `append` function is not mandating the type of `LLNodeType.T` for the sequence you're appending:

```
func append<NT: LLNodeType>(nodeSequence: NT) {
    // here, nodeSequence could be of a String, an Int, who knows...
    let nodes = LLLinkedList(nodeSequence: nodeSequence) 
    ...
    // but here you try to append it to the existing list...
    // what if it's not a list of the same type?
    if self.isEmpty {
        self.rootNode = nodes.rootNode
    } else {
    /// appends a node by pointing the last nodes pointer ('nextNode' property) to the new node
        self.lastNode!.nextNode = nodes.rootNode
    }
}
```

You can resolve this by mandating you only append sequences of the same type as your

```
func append<NT: LLNodeType where NT.T == L>(nodeSequence: NT) {
    // etc...
```

Comment: Solves the problem perfectly!