# Swift how to use generic protocol in generic class

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a library for state management. It's basically a simplified observer pattern, with just 1 single observer/listener.

Right now I have this and it worked well:

```
public final class StateStore<S> {
  
  private var currentState: S
  
  public var listener: ((S) -> Void)? = nil
  
  public init(initialState: S) {
    currentState = initialState
  }
  
  func update(_ block: (inout S) -> Void) {
    var nextState = currentState // struct's copy on write
    block(&nextState)
    currentState = nextState
    listener?(currentState)
  }
  
}
```

However, I would like to change it to protocol instead of block. Something like:

```
public protocol StateListener: AnyObject {
  associatedtype S
  func didUpdateState(_ state: S)
}

public final class StateStore<S> {
  ...
  public weak var listener: StateListener<S>? // <- how to deal with associate type 
  ... 
}
```

I am not able to do so because in the above `S` is associate type, not generic type. So I got error saying `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'StateListener'`

I have looked at this but not helpful:
[Using generic protocols in generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242831/using-generic-protocols-in-generic-classes)

Comment: Why would you want to make this using a protocol? It seems less flexible to me...

Comment: @Sweeper because the listener block is typically huge, so i ended up with doing `store.listener = {  weakSelf?.aHugeFunction() }` all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S is not the Swift style; using full words is the modern standard.

```swift
public protocol StateListener: AnyObject {
  associatedtype State
  func didUpdateState(_: State)
}

public final class StateStore<Listener: StateListener> {
  public weak var listener: Listener?
}
```

You don't need to manually account for the associated type. It's built in, accessible as a nested type:

```swift
  func ƒ(_: Listener.State) {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to parameterise `StateStore` with a `Listener` type, rather than an `S` type. `S` can then be defined as a type alias of `Listener.S`:

```
public final class StateStore<Listener: StateListener> {
    public typealias S = Listener.S
```

Notice that now you can't have an variable of type `StateStore<StateListener>`s, that can store all kinds of `StateStore`s with different implementations of `StateListener`s. The type `StateStore<StateListener>` doesn't really make sense, [and for good reason too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/5133585).

I would say that wanting to make this into a protocol is rather weird. If you want to give the `(S) -> Void` type a *name*, use a type alias inside `StateStore`:

```
public typealias StateListener = ((S) -> Void)
```