# Swift how to conform to different associate type in a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a state management library. The original design only has 1 listener, which works great until I need to support multiple listeners.

The original design is here:
[Swift how to use generic protocol in generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66758784/swift-how-to-use-generic-protocol-in-generic-class)

This is what I have done to support multiple listeners:

```
public protocol StateObserver: AnyObject {
  associatedtype State
  func didUpdateState(_ state: State)
}

public final class StateStore<Observer: StateObserver> {

  struct WeakRef<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?
  }

  public private(set) var state: Observer.State
  private var observers = [WeakRef<Observer>]()
  
  public init(initialState: Observer.State) {
    state = initialState
  }
  
  public func addObservers(_ observers: [Observer]) {
    self.observers += observers.map { WeakRef(value: $0) }
  }
  
  public func update(_ block: (inout Observer.State) -> Void) {
    var nextState = state
    block(&nextState)
    state = nextState
    notify()
  }
  
  public func notify() {
    for observer in observers {
      observer.value?.didUpdateState(state)
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to create the store with 2 observers:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
  init {
    let leftPanel = LeftPanelSKNode()
    let topBar = TopBarSKNode()
    let store: StateStore<?> // How to make this support `LeftPanelSKNode `, `TopBarSKNode`, and `MyScene`? 
    store.addObservers([leftPanel, topBar, self])
  }
```

Now I am stuck here. I need to create a StateStore<?> of something, which can be either `MyScene`, `LeftPanelSKNode` and `TopBarSKNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to say that what you are building already exists in many reactive libraries:

[CurrentValueSubject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject) in Apple's Combine;

[BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxSwift/Subjects/BehaviorSubject.swift) in RxSwift;

You can also check the small internal class I've made myself, it allows to hold the state and observe it [ObservableProperty](https://gitlab.com/oriient-public/light-observables/-/blob/master/LightObservables/Classes/ObservableProperty.swift).

Back to your question, I've found a way to add the StateObserver one by one while keeping only the weak reference to them.

```swift
public protocol StateObserver: AnyObject {
  associatedtype State
  func didUpdateState(_ state: State)
}

class Node1: StateObserver {
    typealias State = Int

    func didUpdateState(_ state: Int) { }
}

class Node2: StateObserver {
    typealias State = Int

    func didUpdateState(_ state: Int) { }
}

class StateStore<StateType> {
    private(set) var state: StateType

    init(_ initialState: StateType) {
        self.state = initialState
    }

    private var observers: [(StateType) -> Void] = []

    func observe<Observer: StateObserver>(by observer: Observer) where Observer.State == StateType {
        weak var weakObserver = observer

        observers.append { state in
            weakObserver?.didUpdateState(state)
        }
    }

    func notify() {
        observers.forEach {
            $0(self.state)
        }
    }
}

let store = StateStore<Int>(0)

let node1 = Node1()
let node2 = Node2()

store.observe(by: node1)
store.observe(by: node2)
```

Adding the array-based observe API might be a problem because of the associatedtype in the StateObserver.

Comment: is it possible not to use closure?

Comment: so the internal observers list inside the store has to be closure because of swift's limitation of generic protocol, am i right?

Comment: yes, you can not just use such a protocol as a type of property or a parameter. You can play with it a little more using a technique called Type Erasure and maybe get something that suits you more than what I've suggested.